# How to find a vector normal to a cylinder in cylindric coordinates?

Tags: mathematical-physics, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to solve a problem which demands to multiply a vector M and vector normal to a cylinder's surface in cylindric coordinates. Height of the cylinder is infinite and its radius is R. So how do I express normal vector in such coordinates?

Comment: Any vector (cos(phi),sin(phi),0) is normal to a cylinder with an axis in z-direction. Mr.WorshipMe was faster.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it a simple search can yield the answer. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the center of the cylinder coincides with the origin, then the unit vector $\hat{\rho}$ is normal to the cylinder's surface...

Answer (score 0):

Cylindrical coordinates $\rho, \phi, z$ point as follows:

- $\hat\rho$ points straight out from the origin;
- $\hat\phi$ points perpendicular to $\hat\rho$ such that it is parallel to the $x-y$ plane and rotated $90^{\circ}$ in a counterclockwise sense;
- $\hat{z}$ points up.

For a cylinder centered on the origin, and with its axis along the $z$ axis, the normal vector points along $\hat\rho$ along the shaft, and $\pm\hat{z}$ at the two ends.